# Apt-get not working within ubuntu dockerfile

Tags: git, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I am fairly new to docker and am trying to learn by writing my own images and, for now, reading Docker in action (ISBN: 1633430235)

In both my own code and an example from the book (pg 146) I would like to install git via a dockerfile.

My code:

```
# set base image
FROM ubuntu:18.04
# author
MAINTAINER me
############## Begin installation ##########################

# update and upgrade
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade
# install git
RUN apt-get install -y git
***rest of code omitted***
```

Books code:

```
#An example Dockerfile for installing Git on Ubuntu
FROM Ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER "dockerinaction@allgeek.com"
RUN apt-get install -y git
ENTRYPOINT ["git"]
```

However, in both I am getting an unable to locate package eror with a none-zeero code:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package git
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y git' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

So far I have tried.

1) Making apt-get update and apt-get upgrade into a single command. When I do this it fails at this point.

2) Installing apt-transport-https before installing git, as described here:

[apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002543/apt-get-update-returned-a-non-zero-code-100)

This will succeed in downloading but as soon as it gets to installing git again, I get the same error.
This

3) Following the tutorial on https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerfile-examples. Although this is different it still installs the x11 server, again this also fails at installation.

4) Following another answer on stack overflow, [Cannot install packages inside docker Ubuntu image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273412/cannot-install-packages-inside-docker-ubuntu-image)
I have tried to install curl.

Al these methods, with the exception of the first, let me update & upgrade only to fail once I try to install software. I also have no issues if I am updating, upgrading, installing from a terminal on the machine I am running docker from.

Any advice as to how I can rectify this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've just tried your exact Dockerfile and I got no error. Something you could try (suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42981752/3477163) is to update and install in the same RUN command, e.g.  `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git`. You shouldn't need `apt-get upgrade` as that upgrades versions of installed packages (ref: https://askubuntu.com/a/94104)

Comment: I have removed upgrade. I'm not even sure why I have been doing that, only that I was told many moons ago to do it when I first install linux. I have just done it as habit ever since. It is still not working, however I am wondering if it is my creaky old computer/network as it is working for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN \
  apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y \
    git-core
```

I'm not sure, but emptylines in Dockerfile was problem

Comment: Thank you, It still is not working, I'm thinking it may be my computer and/or network as it is working for others. I will try again on the weekend with a more modern computer on and not on my work network. I will mark as answered if it works.

Answer (score 4):

Execute 'apt-get update' and 'apt-get install' in a single RUN instruction. This is done to make sure that the latest packages will be installed. If 'apt-get install' were in a separate RUN instruction, then it would reuse a layer added by 'apt-get update', which could have been created a long time ago.

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y git-core
```

Note: RUN instructions build your image by adding layers on top of the initial image.